# ZFS pool question

Tags: zfs

I've just add 2 disks (c9t6d0 / c9t7d0 ) in my pool

> ## zpool status   pool: data  state: ONLINE  scan: scrub repaired 480K in
>
> 18h45m with 0 errors on Tue Mar 22
>   01:40:45 2011 config:
>
> ```
>     NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
>     data        ONLINE       0     0     0
>       raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
>         c9t0d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
>         c9t5d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
>         c9t4d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
>         c9t3d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
>         c9t2d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
>         c9t1d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
>       c9t6d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
>       c9t7d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
> ```

When I do a zpool list, I can see that c9t6d0 and c9t7d0 and not under raidz2-0, what is that mean are they part of the pool data but not under raidz2 this meaning that if I lose  c9t6d0    or c9t7d0  I will lose all my pool ? If it's the case, how can I move them under raidz2-0, I know that you can't shrink a pool, so what would be the solution ?

thx for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the drives were added as single disks to the pool. They are unraided. What command did you use to add the disks?

Unfortunately, you can't remove those disks since data is probably already being striped/written to them. The only solution I see is removing/recreating the pool, or perhaps adding two drives to mirror the "orphaned" disks. That would leave you with a raidz2 vdev and two mirrored vdevs.

```
NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
data        ONLINE       0     0     0
  raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    c9t0d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    c9t5d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    c9t4d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    c9t3d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    c9t2d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    c9t1d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    c9t6d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    c9t8d0  ONLINE       0     0     0   <--new disk
  mirror-1  ONLINE       0     0     0
    c9t7d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    c9t9d0  ONLINE       0     0     0   <--new disk
```

Comment: zpool add data c9t6d0 / zpool add data c9t7d0 it what I was thinking... this also mean that loosing any of those drive mean loosing all data.

Comment: I've just order 2 new drives, will create a new pool with dedup and compression enable, move all the data acrross and re-create my pool! What a stupid mistake!